# In codeigniter, how will i know which checkboxes are checked?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have a dynamic number of checkbox in my view,like this:

```
<?php foreach($documents as $row): ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="<?php echo $row->docu_title?>"><?php echo $row->docu_title?><?php endforeach; ?>
```

And I set the rule for this group of checkboxes to be required in my controller:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('options[]','options', 'required');
```

How will i know which checkboxes are checked? so whenever there are errors on the other fields i can still show the user the checkboxes that has been checked already. like this:

```
<input style="" type="text" class="form-control" name="ClientName" id="ClientName" value="<?php echo set_value('ClientName'); ?>">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be something like this

```
<?php foreach($documents as $row): ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="<?php echo $row->docu_title?>" <?php echo set_checkbox('option[]', $row->docu_title); ?>>
    <?php echo $row->docu_title?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: thank you for this one, but it should have been name="options[]"

Answer (score 3):

You could use `form helper` 's `set_checkbox()` function.

This permits you to display a checkbox in the state it was submitted. The first parameter must contain the name of the checkbox, the second parameter must contain its value, and the third (optional) parameter lets you set an item as the default (use boolean TRUE/FALSE). Example:

```
<input style="" type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="ClientName" id="ClientName" 
    value="<?php echo set_value('ClientName'); ?>" <?php echo set_checkbox('ClientName', '1'); ?> />
```

For reference visit [CodeIgniter User Guide Version 2.2.0](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)